# retriving value from mysql into javascript

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, arrays, jsp

```
  <%
  try{
     Statement st=con.createStatement();
     vsql="select *  from doctor_patient"; 
    ResultSet Rs=st.executeQuery(vsql);
%>
<% 
while(Rs.next())
{%>                          
<script>
var users = [
  {username: '<%=Rs.getString("patientName")%>'},

];
$('#example-1').suggest('@', {
  data: users,
  map: function(user) {
    return {
      value: user.username,
      text: '<strong>'+user.username+'</strong> <small>'+user.fullname+'</small>'
    }
  }
})
</script>

                                      <% }  }
                    catch(Exception e){}
%>
<script>
```

i am retriving value from mysql in javascript from resultset RS.but not getting result can someone see and help me for this.thanx in advance.

Comment: whats the error? complete code?

Comment: yes complate code but not fetch the value in java script

Comment: are you getting value from db in the same page. next what  `[{username:'<%=Rs.getString("name")%>'},]};`?

Comment: @satya yes i get the value but only one value i have 10 records in my db

Comment: Are you really sure that you want to get every user name from your database and pass them to a script file that runs in the browser?

Comment: Open console and tell me the error message.Remove the ","  end of the array if not required

Comment: @Satya can we use scriplet inside JSP

Comment: @Archer yes that i want

Comment: no.avoid it in `jsp`. use `jstl`

Comment: @sarath sir there is no error

Comment: @satya ok i got it.but my problem is still there that i want  every user name from my database and pass them to a script file that runs in the browser

Comment: @Archer can u reply u  know what my problem is

Comment: update it in your question not here

Comment: @Satye ok i update it

Comment: your loop entirely is wrong. whats your goal here.

Comment: @satya  i want every user name from my database and pass them to a script file that runs in the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not 100% full code, but it highlights and resolves the issue you're having with only getting 1 user in your script.  You were previously initialising the `users` array each time you found a new user.  What you should do is initialise the array outside the loop and then just push new values to it, like this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var users = [];
    <%
    try
    {
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        vsql="select * from doctor_patient";
        ResultSet Rs=st.executeQuery(vsql);
        while(Rs.next())
        {
    %>
    users.push({username: '<%= Rs.getString("patientName") %>'});
    <%
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
    %>
</script>
```

Comment: thanx @Archer i check

Comment: @Archeer. thanx a LOT its working thank you very much i forgeted to use user.push.thanx a LOT

Comment: No problem - happy to help :)

Comment: can u help me for this question http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/51883536?noredirect=1

Comment: can u check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32262995/i-want-to-get-words-from-my-database-and-pass-them-to-a-script-file-that-runs-in#